# CSS animation and transition are not cooperating in Firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox

It works in Chrome. I have no idea why Firefox is making such problems. Text should fade in. It should also change it's color on mouse hover.
Unfortunately Firefox does something else - it forces the text to fade in and out every time I hover my cursor over it.

http://jsfiddle.net/76mfr/2/

**CSS:**

```
.sangwinik{
   opacity: 0;
   transition: 500ms ease-in-out;
   -moz-animation-name: fadein;
   -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
   -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@-moz-keyframes fadein {
   0%{
      opacity: 0;
    }
   100%{
      opacity: 1;
    }
}

.sangwinik:hover{
   color: #55C1E5;
   text-shadow: 0 0 3px #00FFFF;
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<p class="sangwinik">Sangwinik</p>
```

Comment: It isn't firefox's fault, if anything it's Chrome's fault for making it seem like it is working.

Comment: Yes you're right. As Adrift mentioned I forgot to specify which property should be animated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using `all`, specify only the properties you want to transition (color and text-shadow):

```
.sangwinik {
    opacity: 0;
    transition: color 500ms ease-in-out,
                text-shadow 500ms ease-in-out;
   -moz-animation-name: fadein;
   -moz-animation-fill-mode:forwards;
   -moz-animation-iteration-count: 1;
   -moz-animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

.sangwinik:hover {
    color: #55C1E5;
    text-shadow: 0 0 3px #00FFFF;
}
```

[Updated fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/76mfr/3/) (I think opacity was being transitioned as well)

Comment: Thank you so much. How could I forget about this? Recently, I started to learn CSS. Looks like I'm trying to absorb too much information in too short time.

Answer (score 1):

Since Firefox 16, the browser expects the W3C property without the `-moz` prefix; have a look at some [more info](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@keyframes).

This should work:

```
.sangwinik{
   opacity: 0;
   transition: 500ms ease-in-out;
   animation-name: fadein;
   animation-fill-mode:forwards;
   animation-iteration-count: 1;
   animation-duration: 1.5s;
}

@keyframes fadein {
   0%{
      opacity: 0;
    }
   100%{
      opacity: 1;
    }
}

.sangwinik:hover{
   color: #55C1E5;
   text-shadow: 0 0 3px #00FFFF;
}
```

Note that is always good to also include the properties without the vendor prefixes (`-moz`, `-webkit`), as they will surely be droped in future versions.

Comment: Thank you for your answer. It's not a solution to my problem but still it's a pretty useful info.